# In MongoDB, should I store the user id in the _id field or in id field created by myself?

Tags: database, mongodb

Each user has a unique ID and an email and password. Of course, email is also unique.
Currently, I have a id field in my mongoDB collection of user. For example, below is a document of a user.

```
{
 _id: objectID(12345678),
 id: 1,
 email: hello@hello.com,
 password: xxxxxxxxxx
}
```

I am thinking to get rid of the id field, and use the _id to store my user id. For example:

```
{
 _id: 1,
 email: hello@hello.com,
 password: xxxxxxxxxx
}
```

Is that a good idea? Any danger of doing so? I think this is going to reduce the complexity and redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic topic not only related to MongoDB. Google for "surrogate key vs natural key" or "surrogate key vs primary key", you will find many articles with pros and cons for both sides.

You say "email is always unique" - is this **really** true? Also in future when your application evolves?

In your case I would suggest to use a dedicated field instead of the `_id` field. Think about potential situations now and in the future:

- Some client drivers may handle `_id` field in a special way. Maybe they suppress it or run other "stupid" stuff, e.g. execute `_id.getTimestamp()` internally and fail.
- A user may request to change his email. The `_id` cannot be modified!
- You may have the requirement to merge several accounts into a new one
- You may need more than one email for an account (e.g. for password verification/reset)
- What happens when an account is deleted? For regulatory or other reason you may not delete the data physically from your database, you just want to lock the account. But then the email is still blocked for other uses.

Comment: I think OP was suggesting using a different value (rather than `email`) as the value for `_id`. But the overall points you raise are important

Comment: @user20042973 exactly. Each user is assigned a unique user id, which is 1,2,3,4..... incrementally

Comment: Oh yes, I did not read the question carefully. Anyway most statements are valid also in this case. Are you concerned about one additional `_id` field? Just let MongoDB create it. Many other databases have a similar field, e.g. `ROWID` at Oracle. However, usually this column is hidden by default. In MongoDB some clients show the `_id` by default and some do not.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, what you think is right. You should use the automatically generated `_id` from MongoDB to identify the user uniquely, there is no need for writing a separate id of your own.

Two advantages :

1. Auto-generated ids are always unique, so there is no problem of redundancy(repetition)
2. It is easy to maintain.

Comment: well. there is a redundancy if i use the auto-generated _id field. If I can use my user id as an _id field, i can have fewer fields in my document to reduce complexity. user id is always unique.

Comment: There is no need to create a separate id of your own, when you create a document of a user, the ```_id``` is generated automatically which is unique